# Gerar numero randômico com valor da data e hora atual com Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, random

Gostaria de saber como gerar um número aleatório, baseando-se no valor de data e hora atual, utilizando-se Javascript.

Não consegui um exemplo real para poder mostrar aqui, porque eu realmente não sei como fazer isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma outra forma de gerar esse valor é multiplicar a data e hora atual (*em segundos*) por um valor aleatório do [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
function datatimeRandom() {
    return((new Date().getTime() / 1000) * Math.random());
}

alert(datatimeRandom());
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/s8f2ava9/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Veja o exemplo a seguir:

```
function dataAleatoria(dataIni) {
    var dataAtual = new Date();
    return new Date(dataIni.getTime() + Math.random() * (dataAtual.getTime() - dataIni.getTime()));
}

var minhaDataAleatoria = dataAleatoria(new Date(2012, 0, 1));
```

A função `dataAleatoria(date)` gera uma data aleatória baseando-se numa data passada como parâmetro.

Caso não queira passar data alguma como parâmetro, pode fazer como mostrado no código abaixo:

```
function dataAleatoria() {
    var dataIni = new Date(2012, 0, 1);
    var dataAtual = new Date();
    return new Date(dataIni.getTime() + Math.random() * (dataAtual.getTime() - dataIni.getTime()));
}

var minhaDataAleatoria = dataAleatoria();
```

Note que nos dois exemplos, a data atual é utilizada para gerar uma outra data aleatória.